# Single IP address assigned to multiple servers?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, dns-hosting

How could one IP be assigned for multiple Domain Name Servers?

For example, Google has a IPv4 8.8.8.8 with many DNS having the same address.
When I make a domain lookup request to their DNS, based on my geo-location, the request will be rerouted to a Google DNS's location that is the nearest to mine.

Answer (score 7):

The relevant technology is called [anycast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anycast) routing.
Anycast essentially makes clever use of the inherent behavior of the BGP routing protocol. A network prefix which contains the relevant address(es) is advertised from multiple places. The other BGP routers out there on the Internet are used to seeing multiple paths to the same destination and selecting the shortest (in terms of [AS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) hops) path. In this case, however, it just so happens that the multiple paths to this "one" destination actually happen to end in different places on the network.

Worth noting, it's not operating based on geographic proximity but rather proximity in terms of number of [autonomous systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) (entities, such as ISPs, doing BGP routing) on the network path to the network. Often this somewhat correlates to geographic proximity, but not necessarily.

Also worth noting, when the availability of routes in the BGP table will inevitably change over time it is entirely possible that what is the "closest" anycast destination changes, possibly mid-session. This happening will obviously break any protocol which maintains state (including anything based on TCP) when it happens. DNS is an example of a protocol that is particularly well-suited (primarily using UDP, just answering the one thing it received in the current query), but anything that doesn't have very long-lived connections can work well enough (CDNs are known to do HTTP/HTTPS, which is obviously a little bit of a gamble).

Comment: Also worth noting is that it's not the inherent behavior of the BGP routing protocol, but to routing protocols in general. You can also use anycast routing in your own company using OSPF, IS-IS, EIGRP, RIP or even static routing.

Answer (score 1):

The title of your question suggest something entirely different, multiple IP addresses for one DNS name. Your actual question doesn't really refer to DNS, it just uses DNS as an example. A content delivery network for http(s) would use the same.

If there are different servers for the same purpose around the world, then different routing targets are set up in routers each pointing to the nearest server.

Normally you want for an IP address that each router points towards the same destination. Here they point towards different destinations, but towards the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Another option if Anycast routing is not available at your level would be to run geographically dispersed server and configure a DNS system using [DNS Split Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)

Comment: That is almost the opposite, you assign a *single hostname* to different servers with *different ip-addresses* , rather than different servers with a single ip-address. That also won't help you in the specific case of a DNS server, since you need to connect to a resolver by ip-address, before you can use the DNS server to do the hostname-->ip-address mapping.... But that does work in most other use-cases.

Comment: You are right; I read it as "How can I run multiple servers in multiple locations like Google" and wanted to give another option that did not require Anycast.